# How do you display users that new information is available?

Tags: ux-designer, dashboard

[image]

Let's say we have a bunch of tabs like this or with svg icons, how would you show that new information that weren't viewed are now available to the users? Would you highlight the tabs in some way? How would you do this?

Assume that some of the data, like alerts are real-time and time sensitive data that the user need to act upon.

Comment: How about bolding the tab label? Or add a red dot near upper right part of label? Or both?

Answer (score 2):

Add the number of **NEW** notifications to the tab.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

This might help you as references.

[image]